# WSL Ubuntu sessions are never actually closed (unless I SIGKILL them)

Tags: pam, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a WSL Ubuntu instance on my Windows 10 machine. The Ubuntu instance has different users. If I reboot the Ubuntu instance, and log in as root, I can see (using `w`) that no sessions exist except this root session.

Then I log on with another user, and instantly log out again.

[image]

But `w` keeps telling me that `testuser` is still logged in.

[image]

The only way I can make it log out is by killing the process, and it does not react to a SIGTERM, it takes a SIGKILL to do it.

[image]

#### Other observations:

- An SSH session to WSL Ubuntu can be killed with SIGTERM
- An SSH session to WSL Ubuntu closes when the user closes the connection (ie `exit`)
- On my regular (non-WSL) Ubuntu machine, any session (that I tried) can be killed by a SIGTERM
- If logging onto WSL Ubuntu via several power shells with the same user, only one session is shown in `w`

#### Question

It caused quite some confusion that the users were not logged out when I thought they were.

Is this a bug? Is there a good reason for this design? Is it something I can change in some configuration?

#### Environment details

```
PS C:\> wsl -v
WSL version: 2.0.9.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.3693
```

```
PS C:\> wsl -l -v
NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Running         2
```

```
root@ELCON45223:~# cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (root@1c602f52c2e4) (gcc (GCC) 11.2.0, 
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.37) #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023
```